# Анимация заполнения текста разными цветами при наведении

Tags: css, css3, html5, анимация

Я хочу заполнить текст цветом заголовка при наведении на него, но текст всегда меняет свой цвет, и я не знаю / думаю, что  можно иметь часть фона для одного цвета, а другой цвет будет постоянно меняться.
Я добавил код с наведением, но без `transition`.

```css
:root {
  --txt-color: #fff;
  --txt-box-bg: #424242;
  --main-bg: #000;
  /* front page title text */
  --main-front-color: #00a8ff;
  --second-front-color: #e84118;
  --third-front-color: #fbc531;
}

* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}


/* Text */

.head-text {
  font-family: "IBM Plex Sans", sans-serif;
  color: var(--txt-color);
}

.main-text {
  font-family: "IBM Plex Mono" monospace;
  color: var(--txt-color);
}


/* Allgin */

.center {
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}


/* classes */

.front-page {
  background-color: var(--main-bg);
  color: #000;
  animation: text-rainbow 13s linear infinite;
}

.full-page {
  background-size: cover;
  height: 100vh;
}


/* IDs */

#title-text {
  position: absolute;
  color: var(--main-bg);
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 90px;
  -webkit-text-stroke: 2px var(--main-front-color);
  animation: stroke-rainbow 13s linear infinite;
}

#title-text:hover {
  color: inherit;
}

@keyframes stroke-rainbow {
  0% {
    border-color: var(--main-front-color);
    -webkit-text-stroke-color: var(--main-front-color);
  }
  25% {
    border-color: var(--second-front-color);
    -webkit-text-stroke-color: var(--second-front-color);
  }
  50% {
    border-color: var(--third-front-color);
    -webkit-text-stroke-color: var(--third-front-color);
  }
  75% {
    border-color: var(--second-front-color);
    -webkit-text-stroke-color: var(--second-front-color);
  }
  100% {
    border-color: var(--main-front-color);
    -webkit-text-stroke-color: var(--main-front-color);
  }
}

@keyframes text-rainbow {
  0% {
    color: var(--main-front-color);
  }
  25% {
    color: var(--second-front-color);
  }
  50% {
    color: var(--third-front-color);
  }
  75% {
    color: var(--second-front-color);
  }
  100% {
    color: var(--main-front-color);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="front-page full-page">
  <span id="title-text" class="center head-text">Hi</span>
</div>
```

[Пример того, что я хочу](https://codepen.io/m2rt/pen/KwXgaG)

```css
/* REQUIRES FALLBACK FOR FIREFOX */
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html, body {
  height: 100%;
}

nav {
  display: flex;
  height: 100%;
}

nav ul {
  align-self: center;
}

a {
  font: 300 42px/1.5 "Helvetica Neue", sans-serif;
  margin-left: 80px;
  color: #d7a150;
  text-decoration: none;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #283271, #283271 50%, #d7a150 50%);
  background-size: 200% 100%;
  background-position: 100%;
}

a:hover {
  transition: all 0.3s cubic-bezier(0, 0, 0.23, 1);
  background-position: 0%;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/53177191/7394871

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Как вариант, используя из "префиксных" только `-webkit-text-stroke`:

```css
* { margin: 0; box-sizing: border-box; padding: 0; }
body { background-color: #000; }

.wrap {
  position: relative;
  height: 1em;
  width: 400px;
  margin: 60px auto;
  font: 96px 'Impact';
  text-align: left;
}

.wrap>div {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  line-height: .7em; /* 1em - для полного заполнения по высоте */
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.wrap div:nth-child(1) {
  width: 0%;
  overflow: hidden;
  animation: rainbow 5s linear infinite;
  transition: width 1s ease-in-out;
}
.wrap:hover div:nth-child(1) {
  width: 100%;
}

.wrap div:nth-child(2) {
  color: transparent;
  -webkit-text-stroke: 4px hsl(0, 100%, 50%);
  animation: rainbow-stroke 5s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes rainbow {
  0%, 100% { color: hsl(0, 100%, 50%); }
  33.33% { color: hsl(120, 100%, 50%); }
  66.66% { color: hsl(240, 100%, 50%); }
}
@keyframes rainbow-stroke {
  0%, 100% { -webkit-text-stroke: 2px hsl(0, 100%, 50%); }
  33.33% { -webkit-text-stroke: 2px hsl(120, 100%, 50%); }
  66.66% { -webkit-text-stroke: 2px hsl(240, 100%, 50%); }
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="text">Filled Text</div>
  <div class="fake">Filled Text</div>
</div>
```

По этому же принципу, можно закрашивать с любой из четырёх сторон (есть подозрения, что можно и под произвольным углом, при должном подходе, но это не точно).

Answer (score 5):

Вы можете рассмотреть `background animation`, и вы можете легко сделать это. Идея состоит в том, чтобы использовать `background-color` для окраски текста, а затем добавить другой фоновый слой, который будет показывать / раскрывать эту окраску при наведении:

*Наведите мышку на текст несколько раз*

```css
:root {
  --txt-color: #fff;
  --txt-box-bg: #424242;
  --main-bg: #000;
  /* front page title text */
  --main-front-color: #00a8ff;
  --second-front-color: #e84118;
  --third-front-color: #fbc531;
}

* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}


/* Text */

.head-text {
  font-family: "IBM Plex Sans", sans-serif;
  color: var(--txt-color);
}

.main-text {
  font-family: "IBM Plex Mono" monospace;
  color: var(--txt-color);
}


/* Allgin */

.center {
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}


/* classes */

.front-page {
  background-color: var(--main-bg);
  color: #000;
}

.full-page {
  background-size: cover;
  height: 100vh;
}


/* IDs */

#title-text {
  position: absolute;
  /*Color the text with background*/
  background-clip: text;
  color: transparent;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  /**/
  /*The animated layer*/
  background-image:linear-gradient(#000,#000);
  background-size:100% 100%;
  background-position:right;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  /**/
  transition:1s all;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 90px;
  -webkit-text-stroke: 2px var(--main-front-color);
  animation: stroke-rainbow 13s linear infinite,
             text-rainbow 13s linear infinite;
}

#title-text:hover {
  background-size:0% 100%;
}

@keyframes stroke-rainbow {
  0% {
    border-color: var(--main-front-color);
    -webkit-text-stroke-color: var(--main-front-color);
  }
  25% {
    border-color: var(--second-front-color);
    -webkit-text-stroke-color: var(--second-front-color);
  }
  50% {
    border-color: var(--third-front-color);
    -webkit-text-stroke-color: var(--third-front-color);
  }
  75% {
    border-color: var(--second-front-color);
    -webkit-text-stroke-color: var(--second-front-color);
  }
  100% {
    border-color: var(--main-front-color);
    -webkit-text-stroke-color: var(--main-front-color);
  }
}

@keyframes text-rainbow {
  0% {
    background-color: var(--main-front-color);
  }
  25% {
    background-color: var(--second-front-color);
  }
  50% {
    background-color: var(--third-front-color);
  }
  75% {
    background-color: var(--second-front-color);
  }
  100% {
    background-color: var(--main-front-color);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="front-page full-page">
  <span id="title-text" class="center head-text">Hi</span>
</div>
```